# angular reactive FormArray and material - control.setValidators is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have an angular material table in a reactive form, and I need it to show a number of inputs for every row. I can't know the number of rows in advance. Thus, I use `FormArray` and populate it with `FormGroup` which in turn contains FormControl's.

Here's [the StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ujiq1x?file=src/app/sample-table/sample-table.component.html).

If you run it you'll see the error:

> Error: control.setValidators is not a function

It's caused by the *filter* input which is not part of `FormArray`. If I comment it out, the error disappears. But what is the problem with a simple FormControl here?

Can anyone please explain how to fix it? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem is with understanding of how `FormArray` works.

`FormArray` does not use (and can't use) names to reference its elements (it is an array, there are only indexes), so you may only refer to FormControls/FormGroup's within that array by its ***index***.

In my example the filter control lies within FormArray called **products**. First, we need to create filter FormControl and add it to the array:

```
this.products.push(new FormControl(null, [Validators.maxLength(20)]), {
      emitEvent: false,
    });

this.filterFld = this.products.at(0) as FormControl;
```

Secondly, we can't use `formControlName` to associate this newly created control with its input **by name**, as the control is not part of any `FormGroup` (it's part of a `FormArray`). So we have to use `formControl` directive insead to associate it with its input **by reference**:

```
<input
              matInput
              [formControl]="filterFld"
              placeholder="any text"
              maxlength="20"
            />
```

Here's the [fixed stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wfocaf).